# Save windows of Windows 10 before turn off

Tags: windows-10

Is it possible to save the windows (e.g. windows of softwares like Adobe Reader, Microsoft Word...) of Windows 10 before I turn off it?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I can only think of putting the laptop into "Hibernate" mode as an alternative to shutting it down completely, this would keep all open windows, I don't know of a way to save the windows on a "proper" shutdown (like Apple's OSX can)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the hibernate option to do that.

If it's already not in you power menu, you can enable it by following the steps given below:

1. Right-click on the Start button and select `Power Options`.
2. Select `Choose what the power buttons do` from the left panel.
3. Click on `Change settings that are currently unavailable`.
4. Now check the box in front of `Hibernate – Show in Power menu under Shutdown settings`.
5. Finally click on `Save settings` and you will now find the Hibernate option under the Power menu on Start or Win + X menu.

**Note: Make sure that you still properly shut down your PC once in a while to keep it working normally.**